# Dropdown Checklist not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a dropdown checkbox list for my blog but for some reason whenever an attempt is made to check one of the boxes the list closes. Any help would be appreciated. The element is simply a styled dropdown with checkboxes inserted into it. It is meant to open when the anchor is clicked on or something outside the tags is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="ne" id="sign-up"/>
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Tags</span>
  <ul class="items">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl1" value="1"checked ></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl2" value="2" checked ></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl3" value="3" checked ></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl4" value="4" checked ></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl4" value="5" checked >Projects</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl5" value="6" checked ></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="nl6" value="7" checked ></li>
  </ul>
</div>      
<input type="submit" id="signup-submit" value="sign up" />
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
  color:#49494b;
  background-color:#f0efeb;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 20%;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
  right: 8px;
  top: 21%;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#fff;
}
.dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
  list-style: none;
} 
.dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
  color: #000;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
  if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
    checkList.classList.remove('visible');
  else
    checkList.classList.add('visible');
  }

  checkList.onblur = function(evt) {
    checkList.classList.remove('visible');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onblur` function is removing the `visible` class so it disappears. Can you delete the onblur function code and try again.
Code to delete:

```
checkList.onblur = function(evt) {
    checkList.classList.remove('visible');
}
```

Or just comment out and try.

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<br/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
 <div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span  class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
     </div>
```

JQUERY :

```
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
   val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
   $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
   idx;

 if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
  options.splice( idx, 1 );
  setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
 } else {
  options.push( val );
  setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
 }

  $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
  });
```

Note : need to add bootstrap style and script to your page

[jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/0wmczg4o/1/)